# Truncation error - subtraction

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, roots, rounding-error, truncation-error

i try to eliminate truncation error with subtraction in calculating root of function where$$x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2},\quad  b<0,\quad 0<c\ll 1.$$Does someone have an idea of how to change the formula to eliminate truncation error?

Comment: What do you know about expansions with the binomial theorems? Or use the Viete formulas and the other numerially stable root.

Comment: Use the better conditioned between $\,\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}=\frac{2c}{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}\,$.

Comment: It's like trying to deal with $b\to-\infty$ when taking limits. You simply need to algebraically rewrite the expression so that you don't get $\infty-\infty$.